# Pre-select a taxonomy value in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a website for an enterprise which will be used by non tech savvy people (so they're only going to use the admin part of WordPress) and I need to make their life easier by pre-selecting a value inside of multiple taxonomies.

For example, one of the custom post types we have is Job Offer which has a taxonomy that registers the localisation of the offer, with some cities already registered (ex: Colmar). I'd like to pre-select Colmar because it's the most used value for this taxonomy so if someone has to create a Job Offer that takes place in Colmar, they won't have to select it.

[Visual of the taxonomy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCwAd.png)

I looked the documentation of register_taxonomy() to see if there is an argument that does exactly what I want but I couldn't find any.

I'm guessing this issue should have already been encountered but I only found posts asking how to set a default value if you don't select anything in the taxonomy when saving the post, which is not what I want.

Here's the code used to create my taxonomy in case it is of any use :

```
$labels_lieu = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Lieu(x)', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Lieu', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'search_items' => __( 'Chercher un lieu'),
    'all_items' => __( 'Tous les lieux'),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Editer les lieux'),
    'update_item' => __( 'Mettre à jour les lieux'),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Ajouter un nouveau lieu'),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'Valeur du nouveau lieu'),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Lieux'),
);

$args_lieu = array(
    'labels' => $labels_lieu,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_int_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
);

register_taxonomy('lieux', 'posttypetest', $args_lieu);
```

If the question has already been asked, could you give me the link to it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for this you could use this filter:

- [wp_terms_checklist](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_terms_checklist/)

This filters the $args that WordPress uses to generate the taxonomy list on a post edit page. Just had a go with this and the following code works.

What I'm doing here is adding the term ID to the selected_cats param when I'm starting a new post.

Slight word of caution that this involves hard coding a term ID and you might want to find a way to store this in the database instead.

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args' , function( $args , $post_id ) {

  //only for your custom taxonomy
  if( $args['taxonomy'] !== 'taxonomy-slug' ) {
    return $args;
  }

  //only do this for new posts, i.e. doesn't overwrite a post that has already been saved
  if( isset( $_GET['post'] )) {
    return $args;
  }

  $args['selected_cats'][] = <term-id>;
  return $args;

}, 10 , 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly ! I'll ask my tutor if this option is usable but it does exactly what I wanted.

In case people wonder how to get the term-id, I var_dump() my $args tab and saw the 'popular_cats' element which determines what's shown in the 'Most used' tab, and you can then see in order which option matches with which term.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works, please do upvote my answer if you are happy with it! NB. you can also get the term ID by going to the admin area and selecting Your CPT > Your Custom Taxonomy > Click the term you want, then in the url look for "tag_ID=<term-id>"

Comment: I tried to upvote it but since it was the first time I used my account my vote doesn't show (apparently I need to have 15 reputation)